# div width 100% works perfectly on localhost but doesn't work live

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Hi I have a website I launched today [www.leafletsdistributors.com](http://www.leafletsdistributors.com) and the problem Im having is on the Get in touch div box (the light grey colored area) I set the width to 100% and the width of that is set beautifully across my screen whereas when I launch it live the width is not fully across my screen, How does this even happen.

> The Div tag id = above_footer and the CSS is width = 100%

it works fine on localhost and as soon as I upload it into the server and browse it the width is set to 960px. I am using a 960gs but if that was the case than it should not have worked on my localhost as well. Thank you any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: In 960.css on line 23 you have declaration `.container_12, .container_16 {` with `width:960px`
Inspect element in firebug och Google Chrome shows this.
Do you have any other value?

Comment: when you set width 100% it is relative to the last parent element that has a width set. In this case the width is set in in the div with id below_slider (but from the class container_12 in grid 960's css file)

Comment: 1. clear the browser cache and see if u still see the different behavior on local and live. 2. @NiKiZe mentioned the issue with 960.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of `id="above_footer"` is `class="container_12"` and that has a width of 960px.
You might want to place your above_footer outside container_12

Comment: Thank you everyone, looks like it is working for now. THANKS AGAIN